# Detecting a printers ink level

Tags: printing

I am looking for an app, preferably gui like that detects the printers ink level. Specially for the latest models of printer models like HP, Epson and Canon amongst others.

My idea is to solve several office related problems, being this one, one of them. I jave tried the escputil and ink apps with no luck. What else can I do.

Comment: did you try `Hplip` ? (for Hp printers ofcourse)

Comment: USB or intranet connected? - mine only shows when connected to the network. But this will vary in different printers...

Comment: intranet. When I look for it in the Add printer option in Ubuntu it shows in the Network section.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>This is more of a comment, but I am including a picture</sub>

The default setup of my Brother printer *(which seems to use a similar thing to a HP one)* shows this in the printer settings window:
[image]

As it is off, it shows these levels. But it is fairly accurate when on...

Comment: Thanks Wilf. Wish it was the same for an HP and an Epson I have here. Both say "This printer does not provide a way of reading the ink levels".